# Modify objects in a specific environment

Tags: r, environment, assign

lets say I have an environment with some objects:

```
myenv=new.env()

x=data.frame(a=c(1:5),b=c(2:6))
y=data.frame(c=c(3:7),d=c(4:8))

assign("x",x,env=myenv)
assign("y",y,env=myenv)


ls(env=myenv)  
[1] "x"     "y"
```

I then want to `add a column` named "z" to each data.frame (x and y) in `myenv`. How could I do that?

I understand how I can get for example dim:

```
sapply(mget(ls(env=myenv), myenv),dim) ###this way
sapply(ls(env=myenv),function(x) dim(get(x,myenv))) ##or this way
```

But can't figure out how to modify the objects in `myenv`.

That works, but not so "beatiful" solution:

```
sapply(ls(env=myenv),function(x) {
  trying=get(x,myenv)
  trying[,"z"]=trying[,2]+trying[,3]
  return(trying)
})
```

Best Regards

Comment: @akrun Sorry. Toy example so typed from my head... That is not an issue in my "real" code. See the edit above.

Comment: @akrun Your example changes x in my .GlobalEnv not in `myenv` :)

Comment: @akrun Hehe thanks, but it does not solve my question :)

Comment: @akrun Haha yes:) See my edit above too.. Actually solved it but wanted your more "beautiful" solution:D Your solution assigns to myenv not an object in my globalenv:)

Comment: Take a look at the `eapply` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
assign('x', '[[<-'(x, 'c', value=NA), envir=myenv)
```

This could be done in a `for` loop for multiple objects

```
v1 <- ls(env=myenv) 
for(i in v1){
   assign(i, `[[<-`(get(i), 'c', value=NA), envir=myenv)
 }
```

Comment: Great solution indeed:)

Comment: another nice solution i found, that doesnt need a loop is `list2env(eapply(myenv, `[[<-`, 'h', value =1:5), envir = myenv)`

Comment: @user1665355  Thanks for the note.  It looks good.  Please do update it in your post.